# Changing an Image for an XAML Element

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, binding

I'm trying to change an image for my XAML element but can't figure out how, I'm using a sand ribbon button from http://www.divelements.co.uk/net/controls/sandribbonsl/ Any idea how I would do this?

XAML Code:

```
<sr:Button x:Name="Print" Text="Print" SmallImage="/Fsc.Feenics.Clients.Silverlight2;component/Images/16/print.png" Size="Small" Activate="Button_Activate" />
```

(broken)C# code:

```
Print.SmallImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Fsc.Feenics.Clients.Silverlight2;component/Images/16/printOn.png"));
```

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute` to the following line worked:

```
Print.SmallImage = new BitmapImage(
    new Uri("/Fsc.Feenics.Clients.Silverlight2;component/Images/16/printOn.png",
            UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```